# Good practices to return large amount of data in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, koa

I already coded a web server using Koa (nodeJs). I need to return a large amount of data from a mongo database. Large means an array of about 750.000 json data. Each json element contains several strings.

What is a good way to code such a server in order to avoid it to crash?
I'm open to all tips :)

*PS: My client will be Unity (c# or js).*

Comment: why do you need to return all at once? first thing that come to mind is gzip. If it's still not small enough, use some other kind of compression to help bring it down. But honestly, i will try to see why client needs all of those data at once.

Comment: I make data vizualisation, and I want to visualize all of them in one shot. However I can load them by packs.

Comment: If that's the case you might want to process/aggregate the data on the server side too in order to send less data.

Comment: In most case, you would be right, but in my case, i need my whole dataset

Answer (score 2):

Node uses chunked transfer encoding for HTTP by default and using streams you could return petabytes of data in one request without any problems, at least without problems to the server - having the client to parse that data is another story.

The problem is with serializing large data to JSON which is usually a blocking operation that needs all the data in memory. But there are streaming JSON encoders available.

For example see the Big-Friendly JSON - asynchronous streaming functions for large JSON data sets:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfj

See also other modules:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stream
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-parse-stream
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-streams
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonparse

Also, you don't need to send one large JSON, you can split it into multiple objects. And you don't need to use JSON to serialize the data. You can use CSV, TSV or anything else where your data fits it. You didn't tell us anything about your data so it's hard to give you a specific recommendation.

Comment: thanks for your recommandation. I'm using mongodb, so storing data in json. Not specific reason except that it was more simple to manage for me (which is a BAD reason). I'm going to check your modules, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is so large do you actually want it all on the client at one time?  If not another simple option is to paginate the data over multiple requests.

The mongo query can be easily chucked with limit and skip options to the find request.

You can pass that in using query parameters `http://example.com/large_data?skip=5000&limit=1000.`

Comment: good suggestion ! that's exactly the syntax I was looking for ! thanks a lot !